# How to prove that $H^1_{per}$ is an Hilbert space?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, sobolev-spaces

Let $Q = (0,1)^d$. We define $$H^1_{per}(Q) = \{ v \in H^1(Q) | v \mbox{ is Q-periodic} \}.$$
How to prove that is a Hilbert space ? I do it easily when $d=1$ thanks to the continuity of the trace which is definite pointwise but we loose that pointwise argument when $d >1$.

I would like to show it is a closed subspace of $H^1(Q)$ using the fact that $v_n \rightarrow v$ in $L^2$ implies their exist a subsequence of $(v_n)$ converging pointwise a.e but the 'a.e' seems annoying since the $Q$-periodicity is a pointwise notion.

Thanks

Comment: You could argue that $v$ restricted to a face of the cube is the same as the restriction on the opposite face (due to trace theorems), but I don't think it's needed since the periodicity assumption in $H^1$ is already an "up to an a.e. representative" notion anyway.